# Azure Identity provider for resource - failure on container app deployment

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, github-actions, azure-deployment

I am trying to re-deploy into a container app, It worked perfectly until last night even with the github actions.

Today as I am doing again updates I can see that something has changed somewhere, which has rendered my github actions deployment to (fail during deployment) and also now the docker push to container registry and manual deployment doesnt work neither. error from github:

`ERROR: (FailedIdentityOperation) Identity operation for resource '/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/NAME/providers/Microsoft.App/containerApps/backend-prod-app' failed with error 'Failed to perform resource identity operation. Status: 'BadRequest'. Response: '{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"DelegatedResources dictionary cannot be empty unless resource has existing delegations."}}'.'.`

The error message that is displayed on while I try to re-deploy new revision

`Failed to deploy new revision: Identity operation for resource '/subscriptions/SUBS_ID/resourceGroups/NAME/prov….. prod-app' failed with error 'Failed to perform resource identity operation. Status: 'BadRequest'. Response: '["error":("code" :"BadRequest", "message". "Client not permitted to perform resource delegation. Requests containing delegated Resources must be made with a valid Microsoft 1st-party app credential."))'.`

I even re-created new container apps from ground up but the problem seems to persist.

Answer (score 0):

As posted also here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/answers/questions/1604049/error-in-container-app-deployment-service-principa?page=1&orderby=Helpful#answers

The service i.e. github CICD actions and etc seem to be again in order.

In the mean time my intermediate solution was updating the cluster manually via az cli:

`az containerapp update --name APP_NAME --resource-group RG_NAME --image REGISTRY:TAG`