# Azure FailedIdentityOperation - failure on container app secret update with az cli

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, identity

I am using `az cli` to create/update Azure container app secrets which worked fine for several months until yesterday. I got this error whenever I use this command:

```
az containerapp secret set -n my-containerapp -g MyResourceGroup \
--secrets MySecretName1=MySecretValue1 \ 
MySecretName2=keyvaultref:https://example.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret,identityref:/subscriptions/sub/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/myidentity
```

The error message is:

> (FailedIdentityOperation) Identity operation for resource
> '/subscriptions/7cc5611c-e06d-4ae0-9e81-dab09605a818/resourceGroups/app-plan-client/providers/Microsoft.App/containerApps/dev-citeo-mailing'
> failed with error 'Failed to perform resource identity operation.
> Status: 'BadRequest'. Response:
> '{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Client not permitted to
> perform resource delegation. Requests containing delegatedResources
> must be made with a valid Microsoft 1st-party app credential."}}'.'.

I haven't changed anything. I use this command in several Azure DevOps pipelines to manage my container app secrets since there is a problem with `azurerm` under Terraform. It worked fine and since yesterday suddenly the command no longer works either locally or from my build agents, even after updating `az cli` (on Linux, WSL and Windows pwsh).

I think it's the same problem as [Azure Identity provider for resource - failure on container app deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78084799/azure-identity-provider-for-resource-failure-on-container-app-deployment#new-answer?newreg=7abdab5dd009439381231593047ebfd5).

My az version:

```
{
  "azure-cli": "2.57.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.57.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.1.0",
  "extensions": {
    "containerapp": "0.3.47"
  }
}
```

I updated `az cli`, tried it from different server with different login options (my Azure creds, service principal, service connection), from different OS. Nothing changed, always the same error.
I except the `az cli` command of aca secret update should work as before.

Comment: Are you sure the Managed Identity is Enabled?Check once again.Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/manage-secrets?tabs=azure-cli#reference-secret-from-key-vault)